# object detection Training becomes slower in time. Uses more CPU than GPU as the training progresses

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

#### System information

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using**:research/object_detection
- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**:yes (just VGG-16 implementation for Faster RCNN)
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**:1.4.0
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**:8 and 6
- **GPU model and memory**: NVIDIA-1060 6GB

I am trying to Train a Faster-RCNN with VGG-16 as feature extractor([paper)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf) on my custom dataset  using the API.

Training params are same as described in the paper except for, am running for 15k steps only and resizing the images to 1200x1200 with a batch size = 1.
The Training Runs Fine but as the Time progresses The Training becomes slower. It is shifting between CPU and GPU.

[image: screenshot 8]

The steps where the time around 1sec is running on GPU and the other high numbers like ~20secs is running in CPU I cross verified them using 'top' and 'nvidia-smi'. Why is it shifting between CPU and GPU in the middle? I can understand the shift when the model and logs are getting saved but this I don't understand why.

PS: I am running Only the Train script. Am not running the eval script

Update:
This becomes worse over time.
the secs/step is increasing thus affecting the rate at which the checkpoints and the logs getting stored

[image: screenshot 9]

It should run less than 1sec/step because that was the speed when I started the training for the first 2k steps. And my dataset is pretty small (300 Images for training).

Comment: If you have resolved your problem, then please answer in a detailed manner such that it will be helpful to others experiencing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is possible that the size of your input image is quite too large. When you take a look at the tensorboard during the training session, you can find out that all the reshape calculation are running on GPU. So maybe you can write a python script to resize your input image without changing the aspect ratio, and you can at the same time set your batch size(maybe 4 or 8) a little bit higher. Then your can train your dataset faster and can also get a relative good result (mAP)

Comment: I actually figured out. The bottle neck was in the queue. I have a quad-core 16GB Ram and NVIDIA-GTX-1060 6gb. By default the input_reader queues 1000 images on to the Ram with a max  of 2000 images there by blowing up the memory. Since some processes like NMS are run on CPU this creates a bottle neck. Thus by reducing the queue I was able to achieve almost constant timing for each step

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji can you explain how you reduced the queue? I'm facing the same problem. Thanks